# A difficult integral over matrix exponents - is there an analytical solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, matrix-calculus

In short, I'm trying to find some method, apart from numerically integrating, to find the value of
\begin{equation}
\bar{X}_t = \int_0^t e^{A^T (t-s)} Q e^{As} ds,
\end{equation}
where $Q$ is symmetric and positive definite, and where $A$ is a stable matrix. (That is, eigenvalues all below zero.)

**Background knowledge**

I already know that $X$, which I defined as
\begin{equation}
X = \int_0^\infty e^{A^T (t-s)} Q e^{A (t-s)} ds = \int_0^\infty e^{A^T s} Q e^{A s} ds,
\end{equation}
can be found by solving the Lyapunov equation
\begin{equation}
A^T X + X A + Q = 0.
\end{equation}
Similarly, I also know that $X_t$, defined as 
\begin{equation}
X_t = \int_0^t e^{A^T s} Q e^{A s} ds,
\end{equation}
can be found through
\begin{equation}
X_t = X - e^{A^T t} X e^{A t}
\end{equation}
or alternatively through
\begin{equation}
A^T X_t + X_t A + Q - e^{A^T t} Q e^{A t} = 0.
\end{equation}
But after several days of searching, I haven't found a method of finding $\bar{X}_t$. Now I'm curious: is there a method (apart from numerical integration) to find $\bar{X}_t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a few more days, but I figured it out.

First, we want to find a matrix of eigenvectors $V$ and corresponding eigenvalues $D$ such that $A = VDV^{-1}$. (This can be done with the Matlab 'eig' function.) Then we have
\begin{equation}
e^{At} = e^{VDV^{-1}t} = Ve^{Dt}V^{-1}.
\end{equation}
This turns the integral into
\begin{eqnarray}
\bar{X}_t & = & \int_0^t e^{A^T (t-s)} Q e^{As} \, ds \\
& = & \int_0^t e^{(VDV^{-1})^T (t-s)} Q e^{VDV^{-1} s} \, ds \\
& = & V^{-T} \left(\int_0^t e^{D^T (t-s)} V^T Q V e^{D s} \, ds\right) V^{-1}.
\end{eqnarray}
Note that $D$ is a symmetric matrix. However, we are using the conjugate transpose here, so we do *not* have $D = D^T$. After all, eigenvalues may be complex.

The above integral may be solved element-wise. If we define
\begin{eqnarray}
\bar{Q} & = & V^T Q V, \\
\tilde{Q} & = & \int_0^t e^{D^T (t-s)} V^T Q V e^{D s} \, ds,
\end{eqnarray}
then the elements of $\tilde{Q}$ can be found from the elements of $\bar{Q}$ through
\begin{equation}
\tilde{Q}_{i,j} = \begin{cases}
\bar{Q}_{i,j} \left(\frac{e^{\bar{\lambda}_i t} - e^{\lambda_j t}}{\bar{\lambda}_i - \lambda_j}\right) & \mbox{if } \bar{\lambda}_i \neq \lambda_j, \\
\bar{Q}_{i,j} e^{\lambda_j T} T & \mbox{if } \bar{\lambda}_i = \lambda_j.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Here, the $\lambda$ values are the eigenvalues of $A$, and hence form the diagonal of $D$. Also, $\bar{\lambda}$ denotes the complex conjugate of $\lambda$.

Once $\tilde{Q}$ has been found, the final solution is
\begin{equation}
\bar{X}_t = V^{-T} \tilde{Q} V^{-1}.
\end{equation}